# Falling into Saturn or Jupiter, would we pass through it until we hit the nucleus?

Tags: planets

If we fall into [Saturn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn) or [Jupiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter), would we pass through it until we hit the nucleus?

Or would we hit the surface and stop there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are confused as to what the 'surface' of Jupiter or Saturn are. They have a large liquid hydrogen centre, but this is surrounded by an incredibly thick layer of atmosphere, which has clouds, gases, liquids etc.

So you would first pass through the outer layers of atmosphere, falling through denser and denser gas until you float at a height which matches your density. Unfortunately, the pressure would have crushed you by this stage, so you wouldn't be able to enjoy it.

The core would still be far below you.

If you like science-fiction, try [A Meeting with Medusa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Meeting_with_Medusa) by Arthur C Clarke, an awesome writer who uses hard science in his stories.

Comment: And an extra +1 for "...so you wouldn't be able to enjoy it."

Comment: @Andrew: A. Dent quote?

Comment: At what moment is it actually enjoyable?  :-)

Comment: @LarsTech: The view is *amazing*.

Comment: You'll likely also be vaporized long before you reach the core.  It's hot down there.

Comment: Nice and on-topic A.C. Clarke reference. :)

Comment: I don't know if it's a Hitchhiker's quote or not. I never got into that series much. I thought it stood on its own.

Comment: @Andrew: I think he talks about having a headache and thus not being able to enjoy to go to heaven - in the first or second episode of the original radio series.

Comment: Why would you be crushed when you're in a gas that's the same density as sea-level water?

Comment: @Andrew pressure and density aren't so simply related as that. If you think about it, sea-level water and sea-level air are at the same pressure, but very different densities. Hot liquid hydrogen such as in Jupiter would be extremely high pressure as well.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to pass through. Yes if you were to go down far enough you'd be able to find a height that goes with your density but you'd be smashed together from pressure.